# How to have FlowLayout reposition components upon resizing.

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, flowlayout

I want to put `FlowLayout` with lets say 5 labels inside `BorderLayout` as north panel (`BorderLayout.NORTH`), and when I resize my window/frame I want the labels to not disappear but instead move to new line.

I have been reading about min, max values and preferredLayoutSize methods. However they do not seem to help and I am still confused.

Also, I would not like to use other layout like a wrapper or something.

Comment: Looks like a cross posting: http://www.coderanch.com/t/606655/GUI/java/Swing-FlowLayout-BorderLayout. Funny how you get the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

One of the annoying things about `FlowLayout` is that it doesn't "wrap" it's contents when the available horizontal space is to small.

Instead, take a look at [WrapLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), it's `FlowLayout` with wrapping...

Answer (score 1):

The following code does exactly what you asked.

The program has a frame whose contentPane is set for `BorderLayout`. It contains another panel `flowPanel` that has a flow layout and is added to the `BorderLayout.NORTH`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PanelFun extends JFrame {
    final JPanel flowPanel;

    public PanelFun() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        flowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        addLabels();
        getContentPane().add(flowPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                PanelFun.this.getContentPane().remove(flowPanel); //this statement is really optional.
                PanelFun.this.getContentPane().add(flowPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    void addLabels(){
        flowPanel.add(new JLabel("One"));
        flowPanel.add(new JLabel("Two"));
        flowPanel.add(new JLabel("Three"));
        flowPanel.add(new JLabel("Four"));
        flowPanel.add(new JLabel("Five"));
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PanelFun frame = new PanelFun();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**So, how does it work?**

The key to having the components inside `flowPanel` realign when the frame is resized is this piece of code

PS: Let me know if you are new to `Swing` and do not understand some part of the code.

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    PanelFun.this.getContentPane().remove(flowPanel);
                    PanelFun.this.getContentPane().add(flowPanel);
                }
            });
```

Without this code the `flowPanel` will not realign its components as it is not its normal behaviour to reposition components when the containing frame is resized.

However, it is also its behaviour that when `flowPanel` is added to a panel, it would position components as per the available space. So, if we add the `flowPanel` everytime the frame resizes, the inner elements will be repositioned to use the available space.

**Update:**

As camickr pointed out correctly, this method will not work in case you add anything to the center (`BorderLayout.CENTER`)

Comment: -1, This only works because you didn't add any components to the CENTER of the BorderLayout.

Comment: @camickr On completely another note, (assuming from the site name) are you also the guy who actually wrote `WrapLayout`?